# JavaScript wait for function error (discord.js shell.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to Node.js and I would like to send a message (using discord.js) before executing a command (using shelljs). The problem is that my message is sent after the command is executed and I would like it to be sent before. Thanks for your help.

```
//Send message first
message.channel.send('Starting Server...');

//Then run these commands
shell.cd('/home/pi/...');
shell.exec('exec java ...');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`message.channel.send('Starting Server...');` is returning a promise that means that you can use `await` :

```
const sendMessage = async ()=>{
   await message.channel.send('Starting Server...');

   //Then run these commands
   shell.cd('/home/pi/...');
   shell.exec('exec java ...');
}
sendMessage()
```

or

```
message.channel.send('Starting Server...').then(()=>{
       //Then run these commands
       shell.cd('/home/pi/...');
       shell.exec('exec java ...');
})
```

Comment: You should also use `try / catch` blocks with await or `.then().catch()`, for errors handling